# Navigation properties get lost when updating entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to save an object using EF 7 but when I try to update it my foreign key values (navigation properties) get lost. The foreign keys are all null in the database after running the code below.

```
 UserTask s = new UserTask()
        {
            Id = 10027,
            Description ="test change",
            Title = "Test change",
            DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
            CreatedBy = db.Users.Where(c=>c.UserName=="Bob").First(),
            AssignedTo = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == "Stephen").First(),
            Status = stat
        };

        db.UserTasks.Attach(s);

        db.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting FKs in variable "s", for example s.Fk1Id, so that field will be null. First get the instance from EF:

```csharp
var s = db.UserTasks.Where(o=>o.Id=="10027").First();

s.Id = 10027;
s.Description ="test change";
s.Title = "Test change";
s.DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
s.CreatedBy = db.Users.Where(c=>c.UserName=="Bob").First();
s.AssignedTo = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == "Stephen").First();
```

Comment: ups!. Should be: db.UserTasks.Where(o=>o.Id==10027).First();

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't have a s.Fk1Id property on those objects. The fk properties are set in the db. CreatedBy for example has the right key in CreatedBy.Id. Isn't EF supposed to detect it?

Comment: Okay this works, but it seems as if there should be a better way to do it. db.Attach works for all the fields except foreign key fields. So it's not really useful.